# How to have ImageSpan to have same height as rest of the text in TextView

Tags: android

I once use Unicode, to display some image symbol in `TextView`.

However, sooner later, I realize Unicode image symbol doesn't look same across all devices.

I then decide to make use of `ImageSpan`.

Firstly, I create a Vector image, without padding around image border.

[image]

Then, I apply the following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abF\u2611 ");

    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_if_check_box_outline_326561);

    d.setTint(textView.getCurrentTextColor());

    float height = textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().descent - textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().ascent;

    d.setBounds(0, 0, (int)height, (int)height);

    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

    ss.setSpan(span, 4, 5, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(ss, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Here's my outcome.

[image]

I would like my `ImageSpan` version to have same height as height as Unicode version.

But, seems like

```
float height = textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().descent - textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics().ascent;
```

doesn't really help.

Any suggestion on how to achieve so? I post my SVG image, just in case you would like to test it out.

---

### ic_if_check_box_outline_326561.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="18"
    android:viewportWidth="18" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M4.9,7.1L3.5,8.5L8,13L18,3L16.6,1.6L8,10.2L4.9,7.1L4.9,7.1ZM16,16L2,16L2,2L12,2L12,0L2,0C0.9,0 0,0.9 0,2L0,16C0,17.1 0.9,18 2,18L16,18C17.1,18 18,17.1 18,16L18,8L16,8L16,16L16,16Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: I believe you need to manually set height , width and viewportWidth and height to make it small or same as unicode image.

Comment: But, how can we accurately determine, what is the value of the height?

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe this is necessary

```
drawable.setBounds(0,0, (int) editText.getPaint().getTextSize(),(int) editText.getPaint().getTextSize());
```